# How exactly does PHP achieve 'dynamic' variables?

Tags: php, variables, interpreter

I was marvelled when I tested the following code today:

```
$star = "Aquarius";
$star = 11;
```

While debugging, I observed that `$star` simply changes from `string` type to `integer` type. I was amazed by this functionality. In C++ for instance, this is just impossible, but in c# I considered the var variable but it's not the same.

For instance you can't do:

```
var dynamic = "Hello";
dynamic = 3;
```

I began to wonder what exactly happens at the point when I basically say $star = 11. My guess is that `$star` is simply reinitialized since it's being directly assigned to (but this seems weird since the interpreter already knows that a variable `$star` has been declared earlier). Can anyone help with some clear or *official source-backed* explanation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C/C++ the type is defined at compile time because of the kinds of optimization that can occur based on it.

In C# the compiler infers the type based on the context and in the compilers brain it substitutes the `var` keyword for the type.  This is why you can not change the type after the compiler made the initial inference.

In scripting languages like PHP a variable is an entry into a Hash Map (Associative Array, a Symbol Table).  This defines the namespace (and scope).  The actual value part is a generic object type that stores both the value and the type.

Comment: Wow, great. So does it mean that in C# a variable is never really stored as a *generic* object type?? And is it possible you can provide any sources where I can learn more? thanks

Comment: C# is a language to output byte-code to run on a VM.  The 'generic object type' I was referring to in the PHP example is nothing more than a `C language struct` with 2 members (I simplify matters a bit by saying this).  More sources is difficult since you combine concepts from 3 different kinds of languages (one for assembly code, one for byte-code and one for interpreted execution).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a dynamic language, similar in spirit to Perl, Ruby, Python, or many others. C++, on the other hand, is compiled and statically typed, requiring each variable to have a type defined at compile time.

Check the PHP docs for some great insight to PHP's dynamic typing implementation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a loosely typed language.  PHP converts the variable to the correct data type, according to the value.

Check this out - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: That's not answering the question at all.